# How to get a number out of a file name to use in cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a bat file that automatically runs a server like this:

```
cd %location_1%\target
start java -jar cm-2.0.1.jar
```

The name of the jar file will change for new releases:

- cm-2.0.2.jar
- cm-2.0.3.jar

***How can I change my bat to automatically run the jar file?***

---

My idea was to create a variable containing the version number in the file name, then use that variable to run it, sorta like this:

```
cd %location_1%\target
copy_file_name > version_number (only the version number)
start java -jar cm-%version_number%.jar
```

But I'm not sure how to do that.

---

*EDIT:*

I got a few answers that rely on alphabetical order of file names. Unfortunately there are other files in here, automatically generated from the build process, such as `cm-2.0.1.jar.original`, so I don't think this will work in perpetuity.

The only constant is that there will be only one file that ends with `.jar`.

***Is there a way to only target files ending with `.jar`?***

---

*EDIT 2:*

I realize my question was misleading. Originally, I asked "How to get the latest file to use in cmd?" What I meant was the latest based on the version number in the file's name, and not how everyone was taking it, as "the latest file created". I have changed the question to more accurately show this. Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

*Edit 3:*

Someone asked why not just use the file name, why do you need the number out of it?

The answer is because I have a few jars that I need to start in different places to run my app. But they all have the same version number that corresponds to my app's release. They look like this:

- cm-2.0.1.jar
- ss-2.0.1.jar
- ab-2.0.1.jar
- and so on

Comment: You have now completely changed your question, Peoples answers apply more to your old question.

Comment: @barlop YOU TOLD ME TO CHANGE IT. Just get out of here!

Comment: Do you have only one file `cm-*.jar` at a time or can you have multiple files with different numbers *at the same time*, e.g. `cm-2.0.1.jar`, `cm-2.0.2.jar`? In case you have multiple files, can you have numbers of different length, e.g. `cm-2.0.9.jar`, `cm-2.0.10.jar`? (This would require numeric sorting instead of alphabetic sorting.) How do you build the .jar files with version numbers in their names? Could your build system write the current version number to a file?

Comment: @Bodo 1. There will only be one jar at a time. Old jars get deleted, but there are multiple dirs that have one jar each that need to be run.  2. Yes, it is possible that the lengths of the numbers could change (2.0.9, 2.0.10). 3. I'm not sure how the build process works. That's a good idea, but I don't think I would have access to changing something like that.

Comment: @TravisHeeter You should add this information to the question. With only one matching .jar file at a time it is not necessary to list all e.g. `cm-*.jar` and find the one with the highest number. In this case the number format is not relevant. You could do it as simple as `for %f in ( cm-*.jar ) do start java -jar %f` and similar for all other .jar files. Or use the `for` statement to only assign `%f` to a variable and use it later. (Note that you have to use `%%f` in a .cmd/.bat script.) There are many ways to improve this with error checking, using variables to avoid duplication etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Filter the outputs to get only files ending in `.jar`, with `Findstr /eli jar`

**2.** Define only the first item in the loop.

**3.** After defined your variable, **`goto label :run_jar`** and use your last file:

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

cd/d "%location_1%\target"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
dir /b/o-d "cm-*.jar"^|findstr/eil jar
')do set "_last_jar=%%~i" && goto :run_jar

:run_jar
start "" /b java -jar "%_last_jar%"

:: code after run your last jar file ::
```

For run without define a variable:

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
dir /b/o-d "%location_1%\target\cm-*.jar"^|findstr /eil jar
')do start "" /b /d "%%~dpi" java -jar "%~nxi" && goto :eof
```

Or...

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
dir /b /o-d "%location_1%\target\cm-*.jar"^|findstr.exe /eil jar
')do cd/d "%%~dpi" && start "" /b java -jar "%%~fi" && goto :eof
```

---

> ...*How can I get just the version number in a variable?*

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

cd/d "%location_1%\target"

for /f tokens^=1-3*delims^=-. %%i in ('
dir/b/o-d /a-d "cm-*.jar" ^|findstr.exe /eil jar
')do set "_jar_ver=%%~j.%%~k.%%~nl" && goto:next

:next
echo\cm-%_jar_ver%.jar

:: code after get version ::
```

---

// Edit `for (so, on)do...()`

**1.** Use only the name of file **`%%~ni`**

**2.** Remove strings **`:*_=`** before **`version.number.s`**

**3.** Use a addtional `For` loop in each (`string` + `-`) file name:

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

cd/d "%location_1%\target"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
dir/b/o-d "*-*.jar"^|findstr/eil jar
')do set "_ver=%%~ni" && goto %:next

:next
set "_ver=%_ver:*-=%"
for %%i in (cm,ss,ab,and,so,on
)do if exist "%%~i-%_ver%.*" dir/b "%%~i-%_ver%.*"|findstr /eil jar

:: code after get version ::
```

- You can also replace `if exist ..` to **`2>nul dir...`**

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

cd/d "%location_1%\target"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
dir/b/o-d "*-*.jar"^|findstr/eil jar
')do set "_ver=%%~ni" && goto %:next

:next
set "_ver=%_ver:*-=%"
for %%i in (cm,ss,ab,and,so,on
)do 2>nul dir/b "%%~i-%_ver%.*"|findstr/eil jar

:: code after get version ::
```

- Or with `if exist (start)` ...

```bat
@echo off 

:: code before loop ::

set "_file=cm,ss,ab"
cd/d "%location_1%\target"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
dir/b/o-d "*-*.jar"^|findstr/eil jar
')do set "_ver=%%~ni" && goto %:next

:next
set "_ver=%_ver:*-=%"
for %%i in (%_file%)do if exist "%%~i-%_ver%.jar" (
   <con: start "SS" /b java -jar "%%~i-%_ver%.jar" )

:: code after get version ::
```

Comment: This is only starting the first server. How can I get just the version number in a variable?

Comment: I tried your updated answer, and `start "SS" java -jar cm-%_jar_ver%.jar` printed out as this: `start "SS" java -jar cm-.jar`. So the version is not being saved in _jar_ver.

Comment: this would be much clearer if you wrote JVM Version .. 'cos otherwise it's not clear what version you or he is talking about in his comment about getting the version number.

Comment: @barlop Maybe you need to reread the question. I have a jar file with a version number in its name, `cm-2.0.1.jar`, and I need to run that jar even when that version number changes. I'm not sure what JVM version has to do with it.

Comment: You didn't write the word "version" in your question,. but anyhow,  Usually jar files that are later versions were created at a later date/time.  So their timestamp(which includes date), is later.  So won't running the latest jar file be what you want?

Comment: I’ll see this again, but in 3-4h from now, I’m not I’m my place...

Answer (score 0):

List the files alphabetically and get the last one with a `for /f` loop:

```
cd /d "%location_1%\target"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on /a-d cm-*.jar') do set "filename=%%a"
start java -jar "%filename%"
```

**EDIT** `dir` might also match shortnames (`CM-201~1.JAR` for `cm-2.0.1.jarAnythingElse`.
And you said `The only constant is that there will be only one file that ends with .jar`.
This makes this task quite trivial (no need to sort anything) by using `where` instead of `dir` (`where` doesn't account for shortnames):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r . cm-*.jar') do set "filename=%%a"
echo %filename%
```

This give you the Full Qualified File Name (including drive, path, name and extension). See `for /?`, especially the "Modifiers" section, which explains how to get just parts of that FQFN, for example `...do set "filename=%%~nxa"` for just the filename plus extension.

Comment: latest so /od not last so not /on

Comment: @barlop:  depends. "Latest by date" might not be the same as "latest by version (filename)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this will not always work because there are other files in the folder that are created during build (so date created will probably not work either. The only certainty is there will be only one file ending in `.jar`). Is there a way to target only files ending with `.jar` in this loop?

Comment: @Travis: I don't understand your comment. This looks only for files matching `cm-*.jar` (adapt this pattern to your needs). If there is only one matching file, you will get its name (if there are more of them, it gets the last match).

Comment: @Stephan Ah, you're right! I only read the first sentence. However, I'm getting `File Not Found` after this line: `>for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /on /a-d cm-*.jar') do set "filename=%a"` and the start line looks like this: `start "Session Server" java -jar " Directory of C:\...\target"`

Comment: That means there is no such file in the currently selected folder (you *did* `cd` into the correct folder before? Alternatively use `dir /on /a-d "%location_1%\target\cm-*.jar"` )

Comment: Yes. I cleaned it up a little bit and now it's saying `start "Session Server" java -jar "               0 Dir(s)  ... bytes free"` Looks like the loop is printing the folder details instead of just the names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124132/discussion-between-travis-heeter-and-stephan).

Comment: @Stephan what  are you talking about.. "latest by version" when we are speaking of DIR.. this is not git..   Also he did ask about "version" to somebody in comment but it seems he meant JVM version. Anyhow DIR has nothing to do with "version".

Comment: @barlop: I'm speaking of `the version number in the file name` as requested in the question.   This has nothing to do with git.

Comment: @Travis: sorry, I forgot the `/b` switch for the `dir` command. Edited, please try again.

Comment: @Stephan You write ": I'm speaking of the version number in the file name as requested in the question. "  <-- He only now changed his question to mention that. It didn't even have the word "version" in it before.

Answer (score 0):

List the bare names of the file, order by date ascending and keep the last one:

```
cd /D "%location_1%\target"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B /O:D cm-*.jar') do set File=%%a
echo %File%
start java -jar "%File%"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are other files in the folder created by the build process, so ordering by date may not work. I apologize for leaving that fact out of the original question. I have updated it to show that.

Comment: @TravisHeeter  DIR /O:D will order by both date and time.(which you'd see if you tried it out). So that FOR line with dir /a-d /b /od as he(the answerer), has done, will pick the very last file in your folder of many files   And he(the answerer), is picking the lastest JAR file.  Really if you tried his example you'd see that.

Comment: @barlop OK, I ran this and got `>start "SS" java -jar ""`

Comment: @TravisHeeter: Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to additional information in a comment, there is only one matching .jar file at a time for every different .jar. With this precondition it is not necessary to list all matching files and find the one with the latest modification time or the highest version number in the file name.

You can do it as simple as

```
cd %location_1%\target

rem If there is no matching file this will do nothing.
rem If there is more than one matching file it will start all of them.
for %%f in ( cm-*.jar ) do start java -jar %%f
```

There are many ways to improve this basic concept, e.g. add some error checking

```
cd %location_1%\target

if not exist cm-*.jar goto missing

for %%f in ( cm-*.jar ) do start java -jar %%f

goto eof

:missing
rem do some error reporting or error handling
```

or save the file name to a variable and use it later.

```
setlocal

cd %location_1%\target

set cmjar=

rem In case there is more than one matching file, the variable value will be the one found last.
rem If no file was found, the variable value will remain empty.
for %%f in ( cm-*.jar ) do set cmjar=%%f

rem Maybe check for empty value as handle this as an error.

start java -jar %cmjar%

endlocal
```

---

**Edit** as a response to [Stephan](https://superuser.com/users/217811/stephan)'s comment regarding

```
for %%f in ( cm-*.jar ) do ...
```

> may give false positives if short names are enabled

As the OP wrote in a comment "*There will only be one jar at a time.*" I assume there will not be a different .jar file that would match the file name pattern by its short or long name.

If the pattern matches both the short and the long name, the `for` loop will be executed only once for the matching file, not twice with both the short and long names.

To avoid getting false positives by matching a short name, the pattern can be changed to contain two or three dots because short names will not contain mor than one dot.

Example:

```
for %%f in ( cm-*.*.jar ) do start java -jar %%f
```

will match e.g.

```
cm-1.2.3.jar
```

but not a short name like

```
CM-123~1.JAR
```

To avoid possible false positives by matching a short file name, change all patterns `cm-*.jar` to `cm-*.*.jar` or `cm-*.*.*.jar` in the code snippets above.

Comment: may give false positives if short names are enabled. (That's why I used `where` and ItWasn'tMe used `findstr`). (@harrymc, your answer has the same issue btw)